# How to use MongoListField to return a list

Tags: scala, mongodb, lift

I am learning lift and mongodb. I encountered a problem as following. I will bypass some code for simplicity. Here is the code:

```
object User extends User with MetaMegaProtoUser[User] {

}

class User extends MegaProtoUser[User] {
  def meta = User

  //record the post list that user like
  object likePostList extends MongoListField[User, ObjectId](this)

  def test()
  {
    val list:  = this.likePostList
    println(list.length)
  }
}

error: value length is not a member of object User.this.likePostList
this.likePostList.length
```

I can store the ObjectId data in MongoDB. But the MongoListField does not return a list. Why? How to use it as a List.

I try to add type case it to List[OjbectId] or List[String] but without luck.

```
val list: List[ObjectId] = this.likePostList.asInstanceOf[List[Object]]
```

Got error: 
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.cosiin.model.User$likePostList$ cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.List

I think I am using MongoListField the wrong way. But I do not know how to use it.
Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: I solved it. Use the value attribute will return what I want.                 val list: List[ObjectId] = this.likePostList.value

Comment: You can also make it more type safe changing ObjectId to your actual model class. In your case Like ?

Answer (score 0):

Fields you declare in Lift Records are field objects, not the actual values contained within the field. In order to access the actual value you need to call:

```
this.likePostList.get
```

or if the field is optional

```
this.likePostList.valueBox
```

which returns a `scala.Option` like object.

If you think of it, this makes very much sense because you're actually declaring `likePostList` to be an instance of `MongoListField` when you type:

```
object likePostList extends MongoListField[User, ObjectId](this)
```

as opposed to

```
val likePostList: List[ObjectId] = ...
```

there's no magic Scala can do to automatically convert that to `List[ObjectId]`. It's the same as:

```
class Foo {
  val bar = 3
  object baz { val greeting = "hello" }
}

val foo = new Foo
println(foo.bar) // prints 3
println(foo.baz) // prints something like Foo$baz$@1d981b6a
println(foo.baz.greeting) // prints "hello"
```

**P.S.** in older versions of Lift, `get` was called `is`.